# Parsing links and strings from unstructured HTML data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML string which looks like this:

```
        <p>
                                Type: <a href="wee.html">Tough</a><br />

                                Main Type:
                <a href='abnormal.html'>Abnormal</a>                    <br />


                                Wheel:
                <a href='none.html'>None</a>,<a href='squared.html'>Squared</a>,<a href='triangle.html'>Triangled</a>                    <br />

                                Movement type: <a href=forward.html">Forward</a><br />

                                Level: <a href="beginner.html">Beginner</a><br />
            Sport: <a href="no.html">No</a><br/>Force: <a href="pull.html">Pull</a><br/>              <span style="float:left;">Your Rating:&nbsp;</span> <div id="headersmallrating" style="float:left; line-height:20px;"><a href="rate.html">Login to rate</a></div><br />

        </p>
```

In other words slightly unstructured. I want to be able to first detect the strings `Type` and `Main Type` plus their links (and link text). I have tried with detecting the words with regular expression, but that does not serve any good purpose. How does one handle this kind of dodgy data?

Comment: Can you post exactly what the results you want are? I may be a bit blind but there's no Size up there, just Type...

Comment: Sorry i have corrected the post. `Type`, `Main Type, `Wheel` are such attributes im looking for. Some of them can have more links, but a new attribute will always start as a pure text with colon.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get `Tough` and `wee.html` for Type, `Abnormal` and `abnormal.html` for `Main Type`, etc?

Comment: @Nanashi, that is exactly what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I know the categories beforehand like `Type`, `Force`, etc, it's perhaps easier to prepare a list in advance.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import re

ofile = open("test.html", "rb")
soup = bsoup(ofile)
soup.prettify()

categories = ["Type:","Main Type:","Wheel:","Movement type:","Level:","Sport:","Force:"]
for category in categories:
    f = soup.find(text=re.compile(category)).next_sibling
    string = f.get_text()
    ref = f.get("href")
    print "%s %s (%s)" % (category, string, ref)
```

**Result:**

```
Type: Tough (wee.html)
Main Type: Abnormal (abnormal.html)
Wheel: None (none.html)
Movement type: Forward (forward.html)
Level: Beginner (beginner.html)
Sport: No (no.html)
Force: Pull (pull.html)
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Let me know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

This will handle `Wheel` properly if it has multiple elements after it.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup, Tag
import re

ofile = open("unstructured.html", "rb")
soup = bsoup(ofile)
soup.prettify()

categories = ["Type:","Main Type:","Wheel:","Movement type:","Level:","Sport:","Force:"]
for category in categories:
    wheel_list = []
    f = soup.find(text=re.compile(category)).next_sibling
    if category != "Wheel:":
        string = f.get_text()
        ref = f.get("href")
        print "%s %s (%s)" % (category, string, ref)
    else:
        while f.name == "a":
            content = f.contents[0]
            res = f.get("href")
            wheel_list.append("%s (%s)" % (content, res))
            f = f.find_next()
        ref = ", ".join(wheel_list)
        print "%s %s" % (category, ref)
```

**Result:**

```
Type: Tough (wee.html)
Main Type: Abnormal (abnormal.html)
Wheel: None (none.html), Squared (squared.html), Triangled (triangle.html)
Movement type: Forward (forward.html)
Level: Beginner (beginner.html)
Sport: No (no.html)
Force: Pull (pull.html)
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: It works like a charm, there is though one little detail i forgot, `Wheel` can consist of multiple links `(1..x)`, can this be extracted?

Comment: Edit your post and post a sample of multiple links for `Wheel` so we have a structure to work on. :)

Comment: @JavaCake: Kindly see the edit above. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for elem in soup(text=re.compile(r'Type:')):
    print elem.next_sibling.text, elem.next_sibling.get('href')
```

and do the same for `Size:`

Comment: So far so good, unfortunately this method takes a link aswell a few lines later in the element list. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @JavaCake If it is totally unstructured, i think you will have to go one link at a time. I am not sure if we can write a generic routine in such a case

Comment: I will post the entire example instead, it seems to be a bit more a challenge than i expected.

Comment: I have updated my question with the full HTML content.